# Setting the integer value of browser.backspace to 2 within Firefox's about:config does not enable backspace

Tags: firefox, 15.04, configuration

I am not sure as to why this doesn't work. I am currently using a Linux Ubuntu 15.04.2 LTS.

Also, is about:config called advanced preferences?

Edit: If anyone is looking for an alternative, `ALT + [Leftkey]` will go back